# PowerShell Client to Server request queue

Tags: forms, powershell, request, queue

**Background Info**

I am currently using an INI file system to pass requests/variables between a client (A desktop PowerShell form) and a server.

At the moment the system works by the PowerShell form creating an INI file which is dropped into a folder on a server. A scheduled task is set up on the server that runs a PowerShell script every 5mins. The script reads in all the INI files within the folder and process them differently depending on INI file content.

**Question**

I want to replicate the INI file system I have above but using some sort of request system. Does PowerShell have a built in way of sending Requests/Variables (Client to Server) to another script using a request queue system or anything similar?

Any advice on this would be appreciated, Cheers.

Comment: Maybe you can use the .net `System.Collections.Queue` .Have a look here : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2011/04/04/scaling-and-queuing-powershell-background-jobs.aspx

Comment: I think `System.Collections.Queue` and jobs are local to the script being run. I need a queue that is kept on the server all the time so that the client scripts can send request remotely to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server runs Windows Server, then you can use MSMQ. It is built into Windows Server OSes (2003,2008,2012). There are .NET classes that can be used from a PS script. Here is an overview page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx. There are VB and VBScript code examples, that should be pretty easy to translate into PS.

Your app on the server would create a queue and register it with Actice Directory (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms707115(v=vs.85).aspx).

Your app on the client would need to locate the queue (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701440(v=vs.85).aspx)

Both sides need to open the queue, the server side opens it with receiving access and the client side with sending access. (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms700132(v=vs.85).aspx)

The client side sends to the queue (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms699823(v=vs.85).aspx)

The server side reads from the queue (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701293(v=vs.85).aspx). It then executes the request in the INI file.

The OP doesn't say whether the client needs a response or not. If a response is needed then from what I can tell, another queue - a response queue - is used.

If MSMQ is not an option you could roll solution you own using .NET TCP.  If that isn't an option then maybe WCF (Windows communication foundation), but that would require using C# or VB. .NET remoting is an older technology, but might be easier to use than WCF.

Maybe you could use powershell jobs, in which the job carries the INI file. The job executes on the same machine as your server script and drops the ini file in a directory and then wakes up the server. See the System.Threading namespace for synchronization primitives like Mutexes and Semaphores.

As you can see there are lots of options, but they all have tradeoffs.